# SQLite: how to totally clear the shared-cache?

Tags: sqlite

I'm experimenting with enabling the shared cache in a SQLite implementation I'm working on. In the actual app everything works fine, but my unit tests are now failing with "`disk I/O error`"s. I'm assuming this is because the shared cache is making assumptions about the file that are no longer valid once it's been deleted.

How can I clear out this shared cache data? I've tried running `sqlite3_shutdown()` followed by `sqlite3_initialize()` but the problems persist.

Comment: It is not possible to debug with without seeing the code. Anyway, why do you think you need the shared-cache mode?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually discovered that some of my tests weren't closing connections properly, and *that* was the source of my problem - shared-cache was just highlighting it (though I'm not 100% sure why).

That said, in my journey, I did manage to find a way to control where SQLite puts its temporary files. the `sqlite3_temp_directory` global variable lets you define it - by default it's blank and defers to the OS, I think.

If you set that directory you can manually clear out any files whenever you wish.